# Нужно удалить пятно которое находится внутри полигона

Tags: python, pil

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть один минус, дело в то что каждый раз меняю полигоны и от этого меняется пятно внутри, (пятно от линейки на карте) позиция цвета в пикселях меняется, если удалю данный цвет то и удалится сам полигон, полигон рисую на PILе , получаю скрин границы города(полигон) вместе с линейкой и отрисовываю его через PIL!